# Heroku Procfile - running npm start

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

package.json

```
{
  //Other stuff here

  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "./scripts/prestart.sh",
    "start": "./scripts/start.sh"
  }
}
```

prestart.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex
webpack
```

start.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -ex
http-server -p $PORT
```

Procfile

```
web: npm start
```

When I push to heroku, I get an application error. So I ran a `heroku run bash`, and noticed that the prestart and start scripts were not run at all (running prestart calls webpack - which will create a generated folder with js file).

Any ideas to solve this ?

EDIT:

1. Webpack now works when i put it in postinstall, instead of prestart.
2. http-server does not run though. When I run `heroku logs --tail`, I do not see any output from http-server.

Output of `heroku logs --tail`

```
2015-06-23T18:05:55.628044+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-06-23T18:05:55.628049+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-06-23T18:05:55.582057+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ** by ***
2015-06-23T18:05:55.582057+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by ****
2015-06-23T18:07:49.114534+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bash` by ****
2015-06-23T18:07:54.748361+00:00 heroku[run.8851]: Starting process with command `bash`
2015-06-23T18:07:54.701235+00:00 heroku[run.8851]: Awaiting client
2015-06-23T18:07:54.808283+00:00 heroku[run.8851]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-23T18:22:20.007391+00:00 heroku[run.8851]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-23T18:22:19.997342+00:00 heroku[run.8851]: Process exited with status 0
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `webpack` to build your app, you should put it into the `postinstall` script (not `prestart`) so it runs on build.

`npm start` should be executing regularly, when Heroku tries to start your app. To see what's happening instead, check `heroku logs --tail`.

Comment: Awesome +1. The webpack is now run when I put it into postinstall (still not sure why it did not work in prestart).

Comment: Also I do not see http-server being run (checked the logs and also ran ps in the box).